# Where can I get a self loading CD with Ubuntu OS?

Tags: 16.04

Where can I get a self loading CD with the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Hi Robert, can you please be a little bit more specific on what are you looking for/trying to accomplish, please? If you provide more details it might allow us to find solution easier/quicker. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: https://google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CD / DVD images [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Burn it to DVD with your favorite CD Burning program and you have self starting CD / DVD.